# PHP framework ( Zend, cakephp, symfony ) for asp.net background?

Tags: php, frameworks

Dont take it as a repeat of another question. I have seen other questions too but my primary concern is different.

I have come from a asp.net background. I am in habit of object orientated programming.

So, considering my C# background, asp.net approach, windows platform and my beginning on php (ready to learn anything condition), which php-framework should I use ?

My initial digging favours Zend but I want to ask the experts of stackoverflow.com.

Same question for drupal, wordpress, joomla.

**Or should I quit php and start learning Ruby on Rails ? ;)**

Comment: I want biased answers. Dont confuse me with giving merits and demerits of each :)

Comment: I'm not sure the question makes sense. Two things: PHP's string library is not object oriented, and PHP doesn't treat strings as implicit objects. There's no framework that can change that. The best you can come up with is a framework that comes with its own OOP string library... I edited the title accordingly, if it's not what you want feel free to edit or roll back

Comment: I think he is looking for a string manipulation class that takes a string as argument in the constructor and every method of the class works on that string to manipulate it

Comment: Pointless effort. Whether it's `substr(arg1, arg2, arg3)` or `$obj->subString(string, arg2, arg3)` is just a naming convention. You can wrap PHP's string functions (which are nearly exact copy of C's) in a class and create "object" interface yourself. Or, since you don't like it, give RoR a shot and have more fun.

Comment: Sorry, I asked the question with wrong approach. I mixed two things.
I am fine with substr(arg1,arg2,arg3) but just wanted to know if php has somethink like C#.

Comment: No, it doesn't have anything like C#. It's string functions are similar to those of C. If you require different way of invoking those functions, then you have the liberty to create a class that will provide that for you. Native implementation is procedural.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if there is a reliable PHP framework with much similarities to asp, but taking the parameter of "object-orientedness" I shall recommend you Yii. It's almost absolutely object-oriented. It's the freshest php framework among the "big guys" (zend, cake, codeigniter, symphony) and it's built in the top of PHP 5, which has major improvements on its "object-orientedness". It works on ORM. It has many advantages and it's growing so fast.  Check it out: http://www.yiiframework.com

By the way, Yii is perhaps the most similar php framework to rails, so you may get and idea of it before going there.

Comment: Doesnt zend , cakephp, symphony support php 5 ?

Comment: Yeah, of course they do. But being the newest, my feel is that Yii is built upon it, rather than updated to it.

Comment: thats a good point :) Believe me, I have download yii framework just because of you. I didnt know its a php framework. And will look into it for sure. Demo looks good. Thanks for your time :)

Comment: Oh! You're welcome. It's good to know you'll give it a try. I've been using it for around one year and has been just great. If you don't like it, I would found hard to suggest you any other php framework, and my suggestion would be going to rails instead.

Answer (score 1):

I know CakePHP uses a `String` class and that most of the library is object-oriented. I don't know if this will suit you but that's something to try !

But you can't in PHP use something like `"string".doSomething()`, you've got to manually create the instance like `new String("string")->doSomething()`

Comment: It should be `new String("string")->doSomething()`

Comment: Right, I haven't used PHP for a while, I'm editing, thank you.

Comment: Are you sure this works? I tried the construct `$x = new String()->doSomething()` and got a syntax error.

Comment: AFAIK such syntax works only with PHP 5.4 which is RC4 at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

The frameworks I tend to lean toward are Lithium and CakePHP.

Lithium is built from the ground up to be PHP 5.3+ native - so it is WICKED fast and insanely efficient. Objectively, I definitely prefer it over Cake, Zend, Symfony, Yii, etc. Also, Lithium was created by the guys responsible for Cake's very existence (it started out as Cake3, but was so different that it split off into it's own project entirely).

The one area where Lithium sort of hurts, is the lack of general community. You can get pretty good support via IRC, and the developers are extremely helpful - but it also doesn't have the following or thorough documentation that the "big boys" like Cake and Zend have, which is a shame.

I'm also very happy with Cake 2, as it's incorporated a ridiculous number of improvements for PHP 5.2.8+ (but it's still not entirely 5.3+ native). They have also revamped the insane conventions so that they actually make logical and consistent sense now (before 2.0, the conventions were completely inconsistent from model to view to controller). Cake is also better documented than Lithium and (I feel) even Zend.

All that said, Zend *is* pretty much the status quo. I no longer use it due to the simple fact that it is painfully slow and underperformant. But that's what happens when you have a massive framework created specifically to shore up weaknesses in earlier versions of PHP. I'm keeping a close eye on Zend 2 (which is currently in beta), as the main focus appears to be a hard push to take full advantage of PHP 5.3 (which, FYI, allows lambdas, magic methods, and all manner of other awesomeness).

So my biased opinion is: as of right now, Lithium kills everything else. Not by a little, but by a lot.

Cake 2 comes in a very distant second (not fully PHP 5.3 optimized). I wouldn't even think of touching Zend 1.xx, but once Zend 2 is officially available and production ready, it should absolutely be worth a good, serious look (unfortunately, that could be MONTHS away).

Comment: finally I have started learning yii. It looks good. Actually very good.

Answer (score 0):

Probably need to build this class yourself, along the lines of:

[Manipulating Strings, OO Style - PHP Tutorials | Dream.In.Code](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/54580-manipulating-strings-oo-style/page__p__368442&#entry368442)

You can then use this class with any code, frameworked or not. [Editorial comment: I happen to be partial to Zend Framework]

With decent autoloading, it should be as easy as:

```
$greeting = new MyString('hello')
$upperGreeting = $greeting->toUpper(); // $upperGreeting == 'HELLO'
```

If that feels too cumbersome, then you could create a static `create()` method in your class so you can chain it pretty easily:

```
$upperGreeting = String::create('hello')->toUpper(); // $upperGreeting == 'HELLO'
```

Answer (score 0):

[Agile Toolkit](http://agiletoolkit.org/) is a **PHP UI framework**, which comes with Object-Oriented User Interface.  Pure HTML is produced when objects are rendered recursively. jQuery and jQuery UI widgets are used to **enhance** the output and implement AJAX.

Here is a simple code snippet demonstration how CRUD can be implemented and enhanced:

```
class page_users extends Page {
    function page_index(){

        $crud=$this->add('CRUD');
        $crud->setModel('User',null,array('id','email','name','status'));
        if($crud->grid){
            $crud->grid->addColumn('expander','more','More...');
        }
    }
    function page_more(){
        $tt=$this->add('Tabs');
        $tabs=$this->add('Tabs');
        $tab=$tt->addTab('BasicInfo');
        $tab->add('MVCForm')->setModel('User')->loadData($_GET['id']);

        $tabs->addTabURL('../password','Password');
        $tabs->addTabURL('../activity','Activity');
        $tabs->addTabURL('../engage','Engage');
    }
}
```

Interface is based on jQuery UI CSS Framework and therefore can be themed using Themeroller. Interaction with HTML, JS or AJAX is handled by Agile Toolkit but can be enhanced or replaced by developer. Above code **alone** will produce this:

[image: agile toolkit screenshot]

The object structure is well-designed and can be used in major web projects. Agile Toolkit is available under OpenSource license.

See also: [atk4](/questions/tagged/atk4)

I'm [one of the authors](http://agiletoolkit.org/about/authors) of this wonderful toolkit.

Answer (score -1):

PHP dose not work this way. PHP uses the . for concatenation if strings ('string 1' . 'string 2'). You may want to look for a framework that supports chaining, I.e. $a()->b()->c();, but even then you will have to call native functions in 'the PHP way'.

Comment: you mean chaining? http://www.talkphp.com/advanced-php-programming/1163-php5-method-chaining.html